# OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server - Paths namespace

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin

I am using the [OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server sample](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) as a temple for creating my own OAuth service provider using our companies Active Directory.

The "Download the sample code" does not work and I cannot find the `Paths` object in the following code snippet

```
// Enable the Application Sign In Cookie.
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Application",
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    LoginPath = new PathString(Paths.LoginPath),
    LogoutPath = new PathString(Paths.LogoutPath),
});
```

What namespace does the `Paths` belong to?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the working code sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-OAuth-20-Authorization-ba2b8783#content) and the `Paths` object is a custom object in the AuthorizationServer MVC project

```
public class Paths
{
    public static string AuthorizePath { get; set; }
    public static string LoginPath { get; set; }
    public static string LogoutPath { get; set; }
    public static string TokenPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This class definition is not the same as the one in the sample you link to. These should be defined as constants.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition for that class... From https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-OAuth-20-Authorization-ba2b8783/view/SourceCode#content

```
public static class Paths
{
    /// <summary>
    /// AuthorizationServer project should run on this URL
    /// </summary>
    public const string AuthorizationServerBaseAddress = "http://localhost:11625";

    /// <summary>
    /// ResourceServer project should run on this URL
    /// </summary>
    public const string ResourceServerBaseAddress = "http://localhost:38385";

    /// <summary>
    /// ImplicitGrant project should be running on this specific port '38515'
    /// </summary>
    public const string ImplicitGrantCallBackPath = "http://localhost:38515/Home/SignIn";

    /// <summary>
    /// AuthorizationCodeGrant project should be running on this URL.
    /// </summary>
    public const string AuthorizeCodeCallBackPath = "http://localhost:38500/";

    public const string AuthorizePath = "/OAuth/Authorize";
    public const string TokenPath = "/OAuth/Token";
    public const string LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    public const string LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    public const string MePath = "/api/Me";
}
```